# Does .h need to be included when using header search path?

Tags: iphone, xcode

- I'm referencing a **static library**.
- I've dragged the library project into my app project and reference it **relatively**.
- The `.a` file from the library is linked into my app target.
- I've added a reference to the librarys `.h` files' folder via `Header Search Paths` in the app project.
- Then I add an import in my apps `.pch` file to a particular `.h` file from the library.

I build and get this error:

```
some.h: No such file or directory
```

The project is given info on where to find .h files for the library.  Why can't it see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
#import <some.h>
```

instead of

```
#import "some.h"
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, try #import <libraryName/some.h>

Also what did you put in header search paths?  I generally don't need to modify that to import a class from a standard drag and drop library.  #import <libraryName/some.h> usually works great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  I just got one set  up today piecing it together from the links below. I didn't include any .h files in search paths. In fact the one tutorial told me to remove any existing search paths (but I had to add them back for another library). Hope this gets you on the right track.

http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html

http://blog.costan.us/2009/02/iphone-development-and-code-sharing.html

Comment: Problem solved: I was using "~/somefolder" when I should have been using "/somefolder".  somefolder is off the hard drive root.